# How to add my Android Application on Android Account Settings?

Tags: android, android-account, android-settings

I've developed an Android project and I want to setup my project on the Account section of settings page of my phone, so that anybody can easily add an account form settings page.

Such as anybody can add a google,facebook,viber account from settings page. How can I do that?

Below is a screen snap

[image]